# Is there any reason not to call setIntent when overriding onNewIntent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

While experiencing a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787249/how-to-capture-the-new-intent-in-onnewintent), I began to wonder why we explicitly have to call `setIntent` when overriding `onNewIntent`, and why this code isn't performed already by `super.onNewIntent`.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
  super.onNewIntent(intent);

  // Why isn't this performed by the framework in the line above?
  setIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Intent` objects are persistently attached to the `Activity`, `Service` and other components for as long as those components are running. They don't simply go away because you moved off to another application. The reason for this is because Android may kill the process at any time, but the user may still want to go back and continue what they were doing. This makes Intents ideal for storing or transmitting small (and sometimes large) bits of information, via the Extras.

The `onNewIntent()` method is specifically for handling application components that are more persistent and hence may be called more than once during its LifeCycle but needs to keep track of the reasons why it was called (and hence the data it was called with). Whether you call `setIntent()` or not depends on what you need to do.

If you don't care why it was subsequently called, you may keep the original `Intent` by not calling `setIntent()`. This is particularly useful when your `Activity` (or some other component) does the same thing no matter who called it and what data it provides.

If you have a need to respond to each event individually, then you must at least store the new `Intent`'s information. This means you may avoid `setIntent()`, however, then none of the components it links to will have any of the `Intent` information unless you send it to them directly. This may be the desired behavior for an application that cannot insure the original `Intent` was completely handled.

If you need to respond to each Intent individually and the original `Intent` does not matter, then you use `setIntent()`. This discards the original `Intent`, which is still in there... and places the new `Intent` so that if the user moves away (yet again), they will come back to the same place.

The reason why `super.onNewIntent()` does not handle this is because the core component classes cannot determine whether or not the new `Intent` is more important than the old one. All it cares is that it *has* an `Intent`, not what it is. This is why we override methods like these, so that *we* determine what is important and what is not. The general feeling is that base classes like `Activity` can use whatever data we have, in whatever ways it wants to (unless we override and tell it otherwise). However, they should not (and often cannot) get rid of our data unless we tell them to specifically. **This is an argument you really don't want to have with some programmers. hehe**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. The purpose is very clear to me now. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The docs for onNewIntent state: "Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent." My guess is that onNewIntent exists so that your activity can be notified and the super probably does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I've just removed the `setIntent(intent)` code from my `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` implementation.

The reason:
My MainActivity is single top. While my app runs it launches other activities like the camera activity. When the app returns to the MainActivity, in `onResume()` the (last) intent returned by `getIntent()` would be re-processed even if it would already have been processed before.

My new implementation (working so far):
Store the intent from `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` in a private instance field. In `onResume` check this field for not null and reset it immediately to null, processing the intent once and only once.

See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/vrLdM5mKeoY