# getIntent().getExtras() returns null on Galaxy Nexus running on android 4.1.1 JellyBean

Tags: android

I am using bug-sense for bug reporting. After the latest update to my app, I have been getting null pointers on.

This problem happens only for Android 4.1.1. There are 25 occurrences of these null pointers in almost every activity, and from Android 4.1.1 exclusively.

Anyone know why this is happening?

```
Intent i= new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", id);
context.startActivity(i);
```

getting extras:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String id = extras.getString("id"); //null pointer
```

Comment: all the crashes in Android 4.1.1 ? What device?

Comment: How are the extras being set?

Comment: @blackbelt about 80% Galaxy Nesus and 20% "Android on Crespo4G"

Answer (score 0):

Looks very similar to this even if not related to Android 4.1.1

[Android getIntent().getExtras() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944503/android-getintent-getextras-returns-null?rq=1)

Are you using tabs? 
I think you need to give a little bit more context, code to have a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using tabs. The code works fine for other but not for  certain devices

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem in activity with `singleTask` launch mode on android 4.1 only. 
It reproduced if I start this activity when its instance had been already started before.

It seems that `getIntent()` returns first intent insted of current.
[Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) says:

> getIntent(): Return the intent that started this activity.

I found out that in `onCreate` I get first intent (activity launcher), but in `onNewIntent` I get proper intent with extras. So I've overrided `onNewIntent` like this:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  setIntent(intent);
}
```

to get proper intent returned by `getIntent` in `onCreate`.

Some discussion about this overriding you can find here:
[Is there any reason not to call setIntent when overriding onNewIntent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748392/is-there-any-reason-not-to-call-setintent-when-overriding-onnewintent)