# onNewIntent not get called

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I have started a new activity of itself by calling start activity. But after the activity get started, in the method `onNewIntent` the `finish()` is not get called!!.

WebActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    if (intent.getStringExtra("url") != null) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WebActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("url",intent.getStringExtra("url"));
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: just remove setIntent(intent); because it stores current activity intent so that you come back to the same activity. check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748392/is-there-any-reason-not-to-call-setintent-when-overriding-onnewintent) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the onNewIntent is not being called!!!

I put this on where this activity is get called.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

then its works like a charm!!.

It is because of calling new activity. And [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) makes   `onNewIntent` get called. This [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) **will not start a new Activity**.

Comment: glad to hear . did you try with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` ?

Answer (score 3):

**FYI**

**Debug** at first and  **Remove** below unwanted line

```
super.onNewIntent(intent);
setIntent(intent);
```

Call **[finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())** within  **Intent**

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WebActivity.class);
intent1.putExtra("url",intent.getStringExtra("url"));
finish();
startActivity(intent1)
```

You can also try with **[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) .**

> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as
>   the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may
>   also be set with the noHistory attribute.

Comment: @CoDfather  Refer the official documents to understand the activity lifecycle:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: if the `finish()` is called first, how it goes to the `startActivity(intent1)` ??

Comment: thats why i suggest `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY `

Answer (score 1):

I was using `onNewIntent` for search implementation in Android. I came across the problem that `onNewIntent` wasn't being called when I used the Go button on the keyboard in the emulator. I solved the issue by placing my code for handling the intent in the `onCreate` method also. This needs to be done to make sure that the intent action is handled when a fresh instance of the activity is started.

This posed a problem as `onCreate` is called whenever the activity is restored from a previous state too. So, the intent handling method gets called even when an orientation change occurs.

Solution : Use `if (savedInstanceState==null)` to determine if activity is being restored from a previous state, or is it a fresh search.