# Facebook Share do not opens the link instead opens Google play

Tags: android, facebook

I shared some URL and picture from my application. Using Facebook sdk.
The parameters i passed are like this

```
  Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "" + mDealTitle.getText().toString());
        params.putString("caption", "youtubePlus");
        params.putString("description", ""
                + mDealDescription.getText().toString());
        params.putString("link", "https://www.youtube.com/");
        params.putString("source", "https://www.youtube.com/");
```

It also get shared in Facebook.

Now when i try to click the shared post in browser it opens the link i want.
On the other hand when i opens the link using  native android app it opens Google play Store.

Comment: Hey check out this post...
Might help might not...
[Click me :P][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079070/facebook-deep-link-opens-google-play-instead-of-app-even-when-installed

Comment: Did you turn on deep linking in your app settings on Facebook? Did you also specify a classname in the same settings?