# Facebook deep link always opens Google Play store

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent, deep-linking

I'm trying to deep link a facebook feed post to my android app, much like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079070/facebook-deep-link-opens-google-play-instead-of-app-even-when-installed).  For the most part I've been following the guidance [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/).
 Here's what I've got going on:

For my app I've done all the prescribed things (properly, I think):

1. Built the app and then using the ADT I signed it using the "Export Signed Application Package..." and my own release key, alias and keystore.
2. Took the .apk from step #1 and uploaded it into Google Play
3. Using keytool I generated a hash key using my key.
4. In Facebook's dev console, Android settings I've filled in Package Name, Class Name and Key Hashes (using hash key from step #3)
5. As part of my app build, included an intent in the manifest,

e.g.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="myapp.mysite.com" android:scheme="http" android:pathPattern=".*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

**WHAT WORKS:**

- I can go to my mobile browser and browse to address: http://myapp.mysite.com/some_params and it opens the app and my main Activity gets the params via intent.getDataString() successfully.
- My facebook link is good (I think) because if I browse to facebook (web version) and click the link, it opens the app and properly passes the params.

**WHAT DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK:**

My end goal is to be able to go into facebook (native android version) and click on the link and have it open my app and pass the params.  However, every time I click the link **it goes into the Google Play page for the app**.  If the app is not yet installed I see the "Install" button (expected).

The problem is, after the app is installed, I get the Google Play page with the "Open" and "Uninstall" buttons (not so expected).  If I then click "Open" my app intent receives no params.  In this last case I was hoping it would skip the store and just open the app directly and pass the params.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible?  Note - I'm testing on an HTC One phone.

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer on this? Is it possible to keep the params in the case that you have to first install the app?

Comment: No.  I haven't been able to figure out how to get params through when it hits the Google Play app page - either on new install or the already installed case.  Judging by the lask of answers here, I'm guessing it's not possible.  Keep me posted if you figure anything out on your end.

Answer (score 0):

just put in the head of the website and it will work as expected

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="sharesample://story/1234">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.facebook.samples.sharesample">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="ShareSample">
```