# Android activity getting old values in bundle

Tags: android

In my android activity `B`, I read values bundled in the intent like this

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Boolean mine = bundle.getString("mine").equals("1");
    int pagenum = bundle.getInt("page");
```

When I start `B` from another activity `A`, I give in mine=0,pagenum=0.
And I can read that fine in `B`.

But then in `B`, I want to reload the activity, by finishing itself and opening another `B`. I also need to pass in the new data like this:

```
private void refresh(Boolean mine, int newpage) {
    finish();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AllThreadsScreen.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("mine", mine ? "1" : "0");
    myIntent.putExtra("page", Integer.toString(newpage, 10));
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

When I call this, I make sure that `newpage` has a value of `1`. However the problem is that, after starting the activity, when I read the `page` value from the bundle, it becomes 0 again...

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not "restarting" the Activity. If you call `finish()` and the lines after still work, then it ins't really finished, is it?

What is happening is the Activity may begin the process of finishing, but then receives a new Intent. Android doesn't actually destroy it.

Also, you don't need to `finish` the Activity anyway. just use `onNewIntent` (a little known, little used Activity method).

[How to capture the new Intent in onNewIntent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787249/how-to-capture-the-new-intent-in-onnewintent)